# How do I flush part of the Apache Beam window?

Tags: kotlin, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

After playing with Beam I have to ask here. Is there way to build pipeline that

1. Buffers items for X+2 seconds by event time;
2. Flushes first X seconds worth of data;
3. Goto step 1;

I've been reading documentation for a week and I'm at loss. I can't understand how triggers work at all.

I need it because I want to buffer items from PubSub which doesn't guarantee order but de-risk it by buffering a bit more than I need.

Here is what I have so far (Kotlin). I attempted to simulate PubSub lag for every 8th item.

```
val start = Instant.now()
val streamedData = pipe.apply(GenerateSequence.from(1)
        .withRate(1, Duration.standardSeconds(1))
        .withTimestampFn { value ->
            if (value % 10 == 8L)
                start.plus((value - 2) * 1000)
            else
                start.plus(value * 1000)
        })
        .apply(MapElements.into(TypeDescriptors.strings()).via(ProcessFunction { "Val: $it" }))

val into: Window<String> = Window.into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardSeconds(10)))

val zzz: Window<String> = into.triggering(
        Repeatedly.forever(AfterProcessingTime
                .pastFirstElementInPane()
                .plusDelayOf(Duration.standardSeconds(2))))
        .withAllowedLateness(Duration.standardMinutes(1))
        .discardingFiredPanes()

streamedData
        .apply(zzz)
        .apply(TextIO.write().to(options.output).withNumShards(1).withWindowedWrites())
```

Maybe use of windows and triggers is wrong approach completely ? Perhaps I should use `StateSpec` and buffer items myself. I'm ok with that but then I have dozens of questions what happens to my buffered data if job fails. I assume it would be already acked in PubSub.

Comment: What result are you getting with your code?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a [FixedWindow](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.16.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/windowing/FixedWindows.html) of X seconds and set [withAllowedLateness](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.16.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/windowing/Window.html#withAllowedLateness-org.joda.time.Duration-) to 2 seconds?

Also, sharing [a good read](https://www.oreilly.com/radar/the-world-beyond-batch-streaming-101/) about streaming (windowing, triggering, etc.)